# Show that the intersection of these two subgroups has prime index

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups, group-isomorphism

Let the subgroup $N$ be normal in the finite group $G$ with index a prime $p$. Let $H$ be a subgroup of $G$ which is not contained in $N$. I would like to show that $H \cap N$ is normal in $H$ with index $p$.

To begin, I consider a homomorphism of which $H \cap N$ is the kernel. $N$ is the kernel of some homomorphism $g : G \rightarrow K$. So I construct the homomorphism $f : H \rightarrow g(H)$ with $h \mapsto g(h)$. If $h \in N$ then $g(h) = e$, so $h \in \ker(f)$ in this case. So $\ker(f) = N \cap H$.

I do not know how to show that $H \cap N$ has index $p$ in $H$. By the second isomorphism theorem we have the index of $H \cap N$ in $H$ to be $|HN|/|N|$. How can we proceed from here?

Comment: You just need to show that $HN=G$, which is clear,. since $N < HN \le G$ with $|G:N|$ prime.

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand this step, from where did this fact arise? @DerekHolt

Comment: What exactly do you not understand? (i) $N$ is strictly contained in $HN$; (ii) $HN$ is a subgroup of $G$; or (iii) properties (i), (ii) and $|G:N|$ prime imply $HN=G$?